# Get exact phrase index in lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene

I need to get an index of exact phrase in lucene. The one word's index I get using this:

```
TermFreqVector termFreqVector = reader.getTermFreqVector(docId, "content");
TermPositionVector termPositionVector = (TermPositionVector) termFreqVector;
int termIndex = termFreqVector.indexOf(searcWord);
```

This `termFreqVector.indexOf(searcWord)` returns me an index of a search word.

The problem is that I need to search a phrase, and need to get index of it. If I pass a phrase to termFreqVector it always returns me `-1`, but I am 100% sure that the phrase exists. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it manually. For example, if your phrase is `president obama`, you need to find all positions `i` of `president` where the term at offset `i+1` is `obama`.